# Different serialization/deserilization with java records

Tags: java, json, jackson

How do I use different names for serialization and deserialisation when using records?

java

```
public record testRecrd(@JsonProperty("foo bar") String fooBar){}
```

json

```
{
  foo bar : "test"
}
```

Can I modify this record or is there any modifier I can use so when I deserialise the record I get

```
{
 fooBar : "test"
}
```

Comment: By the way, a class name should start with an uppercase letter per Java convention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`@JsonAlias`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAlias.html) for deserialization:

> Annotation that can be used to define one or more alternative names for a property, accepted during deserialization as alternative to the official name.

```
public record TestRecord(@JsonProperty("foo bar") @JsonAlias("fooBar") String fooBar) {
}
```

Jackson will first search for `foo bar` and only if it's missing for `fooBar`.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed using [@JsonAlias](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAlias.html) as suggested in the accepted answer

```
public record testRecrd(@JsonAlias("foo bar") String fooBar){}
```

Json returns:

```
{
 fooBar : "test"
}
```